# Creating a super basic Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I've been messing around with `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen` in a while loop that printed the output and took input(">") and ran into an issue whenever I tried something like running notepad. It would hang until I closed the gui application. It also doesn't let me `cd` which is probably because the process ends the moment the command is done.

What I'm basically asking is if there is a way to run your terminal/command prompt with all it's functionalities within a python console application?

Comment: Yes; the classic trick is to run the command in a new thread, so your terminal isn't hanging. You'll need `os.fork`.

Comment: "It also doesn't let me cd which is probably because the process ends the moment the command is done." - that's why actual shells implement `cd` as a built-in. The fact that POSIX specifies the existence of an actual `cd` executable is just bizarre. The executable is totally useless.

Comment: (Also, what you're talking about is a shell, not a terminal emulator. A terminal emulator is responsible for a different job.)

Comment: And if you execute `cd` in a subprocess, you are `cd`'ing the subprocess, not that of your shell.